# Can I mark code blocks as production or development only with webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm building React components and in order to make my code more developer friendly, I'm including things like:

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (!this.props.setupComplete) 
      console.warn("ComponentX might be stuck. This may mean you forget such and such.");
  }, setupCheckDelay);
}
```

The idea is to help developers pinpoint common mistakes more quickly. Is there a way to mark this code to tell webpack to simply leave it out of a production build? Or only include it in a development build? E.g., I want something like:

```
// build-hint-development-only
... my checking code
// end-build-hint
```

such that in a production build,  to the code is left out entirely. My goal is to reduce final code size (and not simply avoid execution).

I've googled around a bit but haven't found anything. I gather I could use dynamic imports + environment variables, and then re-arrange the code such that the development checks are done and a wrapper HOC or something that just never gets included in the development build, but that seems fragile and complex for something pretty simple. The other option would be to put a pre-processor in front of the webpack build that would make a copy of the code without the marked 'dev only' sections, but would add a whole other layer to the process.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `process.env.NODE_ENV` variable will be set by webpack according to the current mode. Use it like this:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Code will only appear in production build.
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  // Code will be removed from production build.
  console.log("Looks like you're a developer.");
}
```

Documentation: [webpack - Production](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/)

Comment: Just to emphasize again: The code *really* disappears if the condition is not met. Only an empty if statement appears on the output.

Comment: But does the check itself appear? Oh, I guess not, since it's not needed...

Comment: @IsaaсWeisberg The check (part in the if) will also be removed if it has no effect after optimization (checked with Rspack).

Comment: this is disbale the code for running in runtime...
i have an NestJS app
i try this becuse in the dvelopment mode i use some mock that there size is costing me allots off money
so i need to make sure mck code will be deleted and i use this approach

Answer (score 7):

You can use environment variables.

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') 
     console.warn("ComponentX might be stuck. This may mean you forget such and such.");
   }, setupCheckDelay);
  }
```

https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was actually asking something a bit different. I don't want to avoid execution, I want to leave it out of the code entirely. It's about space saving. Not a big deal in the example, but with more complex checks and potentially wordy explanations, the impact is not insignificant. I've expanded the question and included possible approaches that would do this, but are a bit unwieldy.

Comment: @zanerock If you use webpack 4 (I bet you do), then all the code wrapped in the `if (process.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {}` and the if clause itself will be automatically stripped from the bundle, if you have set `mode: 'production'` in your webpack config. I've just tried it out to confirm this.

Comment: Ahh... so the `if (process.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {...}` is not just a runtime construction, but a compile directive as well? That's perfect. So the given answer is almost correct, it should just inclode the entire `setTimeout` setup in the `if` clause.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you all are talking about `process.env.NODE_ENV`.